# Bin data read differently in AIX vs Linux

Tags: linux, fortran, binaryfiles, aix, endianness

I have a .bin file that contains slopes and intercepts. I'm using Fortran to read the values and I'm getting different values on machines running AIX and Linux. I believe the Linux data to be accurate. Does this have something to do with stack size or endians?

For example, AIX max value is: 0.3401589687E+39 while Linux max value is: 6.031288

```
program read_bin_files

REAL :: slope(2500,1250)
INTEGER :: recl=2500*1250*4

OPEN(UNIT=8, FILE='MODIS_AVHRR_years_slope.bin', ACTION='READ', ACCESS='direct', FORM='unformatted', RECL=recl, IOSTAT=iostat)

READ(unit=8, REC = 1, IOSTAT = iostat) slope
print *, "Max slope value is:", maxval(slope)

CLOSE(8)

end
```

Comment: Why not use `stream` access clause and avoid `recl` all together? Do you have access to a modern Fortran compiler (2008+)? If so, use the `newunit` specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIX runs (these days) on POWER CPUs, which are *usually* big-endian, whereas Linux is *usually* run on x86es, which are little-endian.  So you are correct to suspect that endianness may be a problem.  You report that the result of running *this* program

```
program read_bin_files

    INTEGER*4 :: slope(2500,1250)
    INTEGER   :: recl=2500*1250*4

    OPEN(UNIT=8, FILE='MODIS_AVHRR_years_slope.bin', ACTION='READ', &
         ACCESS='direct', FORM='unformatted', RECL=recl)

    READ(unit=8, REC = 1) slope

    DO i = 1, 10
        WRITE(*, '(Z8.8)') slope(1, i)
    END DO

    CLOSE(8)

end
```

is the following.  ("AIX" and "Linux" are in quotes in the column headers because it's the *CPU* that matters here, not the operating system.)

```
  "Linux"   |   "AIX"
------------+------------
3E C2 61 8F | 8F 61 C2 3E
3E F5 64 52 | 52 64 F5 3E
BC F3 E0 7E | 7E E0 F3 BC
BF B9 71 0D | 0D 71 B9 BF
3E F5 B9 73 | 73 B9 F5 3E
3F 29 3C 2F | 2F 3C 29 3F
3E DC C2 09 | 09 C2 DC 3E
3F 66 86 89 | 89 86 66 3F
3E 5B 91 A9 | A9 91 5B 3E
3F 67 73 25 | 25 73 67 3F
```

In each row, the right-hand half is the mirror image of the left-hand half.  That demonstrates that the issue *is* endianness.  What we still don't know is which byte order is *correct*.  The answer to that question will almost certainly be "the byte order used by the CPU that ran the program that *generated* the file."

If you are using GNU Fortran, [the CONVERT specifier to OPEN](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CONVERT-specifier.html) should solve the problem, provided you can figure out which way around the data is supposed to be interpreted.  However, I *think* that's an extension.  In the general case, I don't know enough FORTRAN to tell you what to do.

If you have control over the process generating these data files, you can avoid the entire problem in the future by switching both sides to a self-describing data format, such as [HDF](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/).

Comment: On Linux the first 10 values are: 3EC2618F, 3EF56452, BCF3E07E, BFB9710D, 3EF5B973, 3F293C2F, 3EDCC209,3F668689,
3E5B91A9, 3F677325. On AIX the first 10 are indeed different: 8F61C23E, 5264F53E, 7EE0F3BC, 0D71B9BF, 73B9F53E, 2F3C293F
09C2DC3E, 8986663F, A9915B3E, 2573673F

Comment: Thanks.  Yep, this is an endianness problem.  See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! Wanted to confirm the problem and you have helped do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your AIX machine is likely  big-endian RISC and your Linux is likely PC or other Intel platform. Just convert the endianness.

I use these procedures for 4 byte and 8 byte variables (use `iso_fortran_env` in the module):

```
elemental function SwapB32(x) result(res)
  real(real32) :: res
  real(real32),intent(in) :: x
  character(4) :: bytes
  integer(int32) :: t
  real(real32) :: rbytes, rt
  equivalence (rbytes, bytes)
  equivalence (t, rt)

  rbytes = x
  t = ichar(bytes(4:4),int32)    
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(3:3),int32),8),  t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(2:2),int32),16), t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(1:1),int32),24), t )
  res = rt
end function

elemental function SwapB64(x) result(res)
  real(real64) :: res
  real(real64),intent(in) :: x
  character(8) :: bytes
  integer(int64) :: t
  real(real64) :: rbytes, rt
  equivalence (rbytes, bytes)
  equivalence (t, rt)

  rbytes = x
  t = ichar(bytes(8:8),int64)
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(7:7),int64),8),  t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(6:6),int64),16), t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(5:5),int64),24), t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(4:4),int64),32), t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(3:3),int64),40), t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(2:2),int64),48), t )
  t = ior( ishftc(ichar(bytes(1:1),int64),56), t )
  res = rt
end function
```

usage:

```
SLOPE = SwapB32(SLOPE)
```

There are other ways. Some compilers support non-standard `OPEN(...,CONVERT='big_endian',...` and some have command line options like `-fconvert=big-endian`.

Answer (score 0):

That elemental function SwapB64 is elegant, and good to have for these issues.
Or
Try these using big_endian, little endian etc.
(Personally I would do both)

```
!OPEN(UNIT=8, FILE='MODIS_AVHRR_years_slope.bin', ACTION='READ', ACCESS='direct', FORM='unformatted', RECL=recl, IOSTAT=iostat)

OPEN(UNIT=8, FILE='MODIS_AVHRR_years_slope.bin', CONVERT='big_endian', ACTION='READ', ACCESS='direct', FORM='unformatted', RECL=recl, IOSTAT=iostat)
```

Comment: I have actually mentioned this. The problem with this is that this specifier is completely outside of the standard. That is not against your answer, but I think it should be mentioned.